# Aggregate (Reflexive Join) in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, self-join

I have the following data in collection "sampleorgchart":
[image]

Eventually we want to use the "Relationship" field in a match/filter statement, but first I just want to get some demo query to work with the hierarchy.

I am trying the following:

```
db.sampleorgchart2.aggregate([
  {
      $graphLookup: {
          from: "sampleorgchart2",
          startWith: "$To",
          connectFromField: "To",
          connectToField: "From",
          as: "myList",
          maxDepth: 2,
          depthField: "depth" 
      }
  }
])
```

It runs, but return 0 items in each of the "myList" fields:

```
// 1
{
    "_id": ObjectId("6180023c68600000010000f5"),
    "From": "John Doe",
    "Relationship": "is CEO of ",
    "To ": "Sample Company",
    "myList": [ ]
}
```

Is something wrong with my query?  I would like to see the connected rows in "myList".

For further practice, I copied the employee data from this page, and got that query working.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#examples
So by changing the collection name and the field names, I don't understand why it won't work with my sampleorgchart2 collection. I got the query that page working, then reversed it to go down the hierarchy instead of up the hierarchy:

```
db.simpleorgchart.aggregate([
  {
      $graphLookup: {
          from: "simpleorgchart",
          startWith: "$reportsTo",
          connectFromField: "name",
          connectToField: "reportsTo",
          as: "myReportingHierarchy",
                maxDepth: 2,
                    depthField: "depth" 
      }
  }
])
```

Sample results:

```
// 1
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Dev",
    "reportsTo": null,
    "myReportingHierarchy": [
        {
            "_id": "1",
            "name": "Dev",
            "reportsTo": null,
            "depth": NumberLong("0")
        },
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "name": "Eliot",
            "reportsTo": "Dev",
            "depth": NumberLong("1")
        },
        {
            "_id": "3",
            "name": "Ron",
            "reportsTo": "Eliot",
            "depth": NumberLong("2")
        },
        {
            "_id": "4",
            "name": "Andrew",
            "reportsTo": "Eliot",
            "depth": NumberLong("2")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like a typo to me: `"To ": "Sample Company",` - can you verify the collection is called `To `  instead of `To`?

Comment: Yes, thanks so much!  I uploaded from Excel, so column name must have had a trailing space on it.